# How can I make the enumi counter follow another counter?

Tags: numbering

For example, in the MWE below, how can I label the items with the theorem counter?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools,lipsum}

\declaretheorem[name=Theorem, numberwithin=section]{theorem}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\begin{theorem}
    This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{enumerate}
    \item The label of this item should be 1.2.
    \item The label of this item should be 1.3. 
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Always? Or just for a specific `enumerate`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set the counter `enumi` to the value of `theorem` at the start and set `theorem` to the value of `enumi` at the end.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools,enumitem,lipsum}

\declaretheorem[name=Theorem, numberwithin=section]{theorem}
\newenvironment{thmenumerate}
 {\enumerate[
    label=\thesection.\arabic*,
    before=\setcounter{enumi}{\value{theorem}},
    after=\setcounter{theorem}{\value{enumi}},
  ]}
 {\endenumerate}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\begin{theorem}
    This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{thmenumerate}
    \item The label of this item should be 1.2.
    \item The label of this item should be 1.3. 
\end{thmenumerate}

\begin{theorem}
    This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{thmenumerate}
    \item The label of this item should be 1.5.
    \item The label of this item should be 1.6. 
\end{thmenumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may want to change the formatting of the label so as to be consistent with that of theorems.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools,enumitem,lipsum}

\declaretheorem[name=Theorem, numberwithin=section]{theorem}
\newenvironment{thmenumerate}
 {\enumerate[
    leftmargin=*,
    label=\bfseries\thesection.\arabic*.,
    ref=\thesection.\arabic*,
    before=\setcounter{enumi}{\value{theorem}},
    after=\setcounter{theorem}{\value{enumi}},
  ]}
 {\endenumerate}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\begin{theorem}
    This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{thmenumerate}
    \item The label of this item should be 1.2.
    \item The label of this item should be 1.3. 
\end{thmenumerate}

\begin{theorem}
    This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{thmenumerate}
    \item The label of this item should be 1.5.
    \item The label of this item should be 1.6. 
\end{thmenumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: might it not be possible to define an environment that overrides or outmaneuvers the definition of `\usecounter` to *not* reset the counter to 0 at `\begin`?  (would probably have to use a new counter, say `\enumj`.)  or is that just too much trouble?

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Well, one could say, _e.g._, `\enumerate[label=\thetheorem, before=\def\@listctr{theorem}]` (which also works); but egreg’s solution is so straightforward…

Answer (score 3):

Well, after all, I think I could give this code a chance:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools,enumitem,lipsum}

\declaretheorem[name=Theorem, numberwithin=section]{theorem}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{thmenumerate}
 {\enumerate[
    label=\thetheorem,
    before=\def\@listctr{theorem}
  ]}
 {\endenumerate}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\begin{theorem}
    This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{thmenumerate}
    \item The label of this item should be 1.2.
    \item The label of this item should be 1.3. 
\end{thmenumerate}

\begin{theorem}
    This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{thmenumerate}
    \item The label of this item should be 1.5.
    \item The label of this item should be 1.6. 
\end{thmenumerate}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Output of the above code]